# Sitecore.Logging RollingFileAppender missing [lockingModel]

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, log4net

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue in Sitecore logging that is generating this message in log4net:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Website\Data\logs\Custom.log' because it is being used by another process.

I tried increasing the MemoryMonitorHook threshold and cleared up some errors. My next step is to change the locking model (as default is ExclusiveLock) using:

```
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

But now log4net is reporting the error below. It seems the Sitecore.Logging.dll is missing some properties? Version is 1.2.0.30715

> log4net:ERROR DOMConfigurator: Cannot find Property [lockingModel] to set object on [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender]

[image: Sitecore.Logging]

log4net config is as so:

```
   <appender name="CustomLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
      <file value="$(dataFolder)\logs\Custom.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />      
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd.'log'" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <dateTimeStrategy type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender+UniversalDateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

Comment: Have you followed these steps detailed here? http://firebreaksice.com/write-to-a-custom-sitecore-log-with-log4net/. In the post the configuration is simpler and uses a different type for the appender.

Comment: Do you have multi sites running on your sitecore instance? Is it running on One IIS site or multiple?

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore uses an older version of log4net (looks like Sitecore 8 is still using 1.2.0). Looks like the lockingModel property was added in a later version.

If you need to use features of a later version of log4net I suggest you take a look at [this blog post](http://sitecorehelp.com/blog/4/Using-custom-version-of-Log4Net-in-Sitecore) which describes how do use a different version of log4net than the one that is baked into Sitecore.Logger.dll

Comment: I ended up switching my custom logs to NLog as I felt it performed better for my use case (writing 2gig logs everyday). Thank you for the suggestion!